# Saving (escaped?) html and using it in a json object

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, escaping

I am trying to save the inside of a div object as some html inside a json object, save it, then receive it back as json and have the html be able to be used as normal html when placed inside a div.

So here is my attempt

```
$scope.contentHere = [
{
  'size' : '',
  'title' : 'Utility Alerts',
  'content' : '<div>test 1</div>',
  'help' : 'Help Text Here',
  'launch' :  true,
  'share' : true,
  'mobile' :  true

},
{
  'size' : 'w3',
  'title' : 'Graph',
  'content' : '&lt;nvd3-stacked-area-chart data=&quot;exampleData&quot; id=&quot;exampleId&quot; showXAxis=&quot;true&quot; showYAxis=&quot;true&quot; showControls=&quot;true&quot; width=&quot;700&quot; height=&quot;200&quot;&gt; &lt;svg&gt;&lt;/svg&gt; &lt;/nvd3-stacked-area-chart&gt;',
  'help' : 'Help Text Here',
  'launch' :  true,
  'share' : true,
  'mobile' :  true

}];
```

I tried one normally, one fully escaped, and both seem to just render as normal text on the page. 
I have them in a repeat and am trying to display the html like so -

```
<div class="item gs-w" ng-class="widget.size" ng-repeat="widget in contentHere" >
            <div class="handle"><h5 ng-style="{ 'color' : themeHere.h1 }>{{widget.title}}</h5></div>
                {{widget.content}}

    </div>
```

Would appreciate any help! Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to tell Angular to bind the content as HTML like so:

```
<div class="item gs-w" ng-class="widget.size" ng-repeat="widget in contentHere" >
    <div class="handle"><h5 ng-style="{ 'color' : themeHere.h1 }>{{widget.title}}</h5></div>
    <div ng-bind-html="widget.content"></div>
</div>
```

However, since 1.2, Angular ships with $sce enabled, which means you have to explicitly tell  Angular that you trust that HTML like so:

```
// You will have to inject $sce in your controller.
$scope.contentHere = $scope.contentHere.map(function(entry){
    entry.content = $sce.trustAsHtml(entry.content);
    return entry;
});
```

Also, not sure if it's just a copy paste issue, but in second object in your array, the content is encoded in HTML entities, you will want proper, un-encoded, HTML in there.

Answer (score 0):

You should push the html into the $templateCache with a unique identifier, and then include that template from your view using ng-include.

Alternatively you make a custom directive which loads the html and binds it to the directive as part of the linking function.